# rsync + Permission denied

Tags: linux

I want to copy the `some_file` using rsync to my machine (red hat 5.3) 
from other linux server also (red hat 5.3)

Is it possible to copy the file without to get "Permission denied." ?

Remark - the login and password on 130.146.120.11 machine is:

login=root
 password=moon

```
 rsync -WavH  --progress 130.146.120.11:/tmp/some_file .

 Permission denied.
 rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes read so far)
 rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(165)
```

Comment: I'm *really* hoping that you didn't just post the root password for your server.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to supply a password to access your remote system. You can do this by using the `--password-file=/path/to/file/containing/password`.

```
rsync -WavH --password-file=/$HOME/passfile --progress root@130.146.120.11:/tmp/some_file .
```

Make sure that the permissions on `/$HOME/passfile are 600` (`chmod 600 /$HOME/passfile`) otherwise you may leave ypur root password on view.

Comment: so if the password is moon the I can only to write moon in passfile? for example echo "moon" > /$HOME/passfile

Comment: please advice how to edit the /$HOME/passfile file ?

Comment: In whatever manner you usually edit a text file, personally I'd do it with vi.

Comment: I edit the file with moon password , but it give me Permission denied -:(

Answer (score 1):

rsync can connect either to a remote shell (default) or a rsync daemon listening on TCP port 873.  Since you did not state that you are running a rsync daemon and since you are not using double colons `::` in your host string  I'm assuming that you are connecting with a remote shell.  It's quite possible that your rsync binaries are trying to use rlogin which is an extremely old and insecure protocol and is usually disabled on most newer distros.  The more preferred option whilst using a remote shell is to use SSH via shared key authentication and then add the `-e ssh` or `--rsh=ssh` argument in your rsync command.

```
rsync -WavH --progress -e ssh root@130.146.120.11:/tmp/some_file .
```

I would also recommend highly that you do not use the root user if at all possible to do this sort of operation.  If root is absolutely necessary I would even highlier (is that a word) recommend that you use shared keys instead of password authentication.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

> rsync -WavH  --progress root@130.146.120.11:/tmp/some_file .

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: try to run: "ssh root@130.146.120.11 ls -l /tmp/some_file" and share the output

Comment: needs password: for this

Comment: @Diana of course you need the password. You are trying to access a file on 130.146.12.11 as root. Either you supply the root password or you set up access via private/public key.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see why you don't simply use [SSH key authentication](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/530). It would be the most simple...